# Validate checkbox with jquery.validate.unobtrusive

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

I need to validate  lows checkbox with     `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` and I use this code but always checkbox is valid. How to solve this?

```
<input id="AcceptLaws" type="checkbox" name="AcceptLaws" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please accept with laws">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AcceptLaws" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

```js
$('#AcceptLaws').valid()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is because your `data` attributes for the required rule are incorrect. You need to set `data-rule-required="true"`, then put the error message in to `data-msg-required`. Try this:

```js
$('#AcceptLaws').valid()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="AcceptLaws" type="checkbox" name="AcceptLaws" data-val="true" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please accept with laws" />
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AcceptLaws" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that though this produces the desired result it doesn't provide full context. Instead of requiring the checkbox using Unobtrusive, this utilizes functionality built into the jQuery Validation plugin that sets up rules based on data- attributes.

Comment: Still, have my upvote for showing me something I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that the Unobtrusive library interprets "required" differently than jQuery Validation when it comes to checkboxes. Unobtrusive interprets "required" as having a value and in the typical use case (as part of .NET MVC) a checkbox will always have a value.

Though the [source is old](http://web.archive.org/web/20130310222735/http://forums.asp.net/t/1648319.aspx/1), the following information is [still relevant](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/blob/v4.0.0/src/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js#L384-L389):

> Yes Validation is not performed for checkboxes because the programmers that wrote the adapter says that required is different [from] mandatory...A required validation attribute must trigger if no value is provided! An unchecked checkbox has a a value: the false value!
>
> See here the source code of the adapter for the required attribute:
>
> ```js
> adapters.add("required", function (options) {
>   // jQuery Validate equates "required" with "mandatory" for checkbox elements
>   if (options.element.tagName.toUpperCase() !== "INPUT" || options.element.type.toUpperCase() !== "CHECKBOX") {
>     setValidationValues(options, "required", true);
>   }
> });
> ```

I did find a way to get Unobtrusive to behave in the desired manner, and that was to set up validation so that the value of the field must equal itself (using the "equalto" validation):

```css
.field-validation-error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation-unobtrusive@4.0.0/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input id="AcceptLaws" type="checkbox" name="AcceptLaws" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="You must accept the cited laws" data-val-equalto-other="AcceptLaws" />
      I accept
    </label>
    <br>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AcceptLaws" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" onclick="$('#AcceptLaws').valid();">Accept</button>
  </p>
</form>
```